# Rails 5 how to access image in public folder from css file also in public folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have CSS file

```
public/stylesheets/landing.css
```

It works fine when using tag

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "/stylesheets/landing" %>
```

I also have this image

```
public/images/1-hero-image.jpg
```

Now, inside the css file I am trying to reference this image.

I have tried following variants:

```
background: url('1-hero-image.jpg');
```

```
background: url('/public/images/1-hero-image.jpg');
```

```
background: url('/images/1-hero-image.jpg');
```

```
background: url('images/1-hero-image.jpg');
```

None of them seems to work.

I will be grateful for any help you can provide.

Comment: From what you describe, this `url('/images/1-hero-image.jpg')` should work. Are you sure the image is there? Can you access the image manually using it's url?

Comment: Why do you use `- ` before `background:`? I tried to reproduce your situation and `background: url('/images/1-hero-image.jpg');` works

Comment: Hmmm... indeed, it is working with url('/images/1-hero-image.jpg'). Now I am scratching my head, don't know where I did wrong before. I apologize. If this is posted as an answer I will select it as the correct one. Thanks.

Comment: @mechnicov: the - before background: is just mini-Markdown formatting, it isn't actually in the css file. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`background: url('/images/1-hero-image.jpg');` is enough in your situation.

But [it's better](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#linking-to-css-files-with-the-stylesheet-link-tag) to use for CSS and images folder `app/assets/`